# How to Get id key from List View - C# Windows application

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I am listing set of table items(only names) in List View. I enabled checkbox property of ListView. I displayed all items as Large icons. I want to attach a key(id) for that items for further processing on that items.. If any idea , please reply

Answer (score 8):

Use the ListViewItem.Name property.  Poorly named, it is actually the key.  The one you can pass to ListView.Items.IndexOfKey() or ListView.Items["key"].

Answer (score 3):

#### Description

You should use the `Tag` property for things like that.

> Gets or sets the object that contains data about the control.

You can set your id or any other `object` to the `ListItem` you want.

#### Sample

**Add the Item**

```
ListViewItem myItem = new ListViewItem();
myItem.Tag = 1; // or any other object
listView1.Items.Add(myItem);
```

**Use the index**

```
private void listView1_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem myItem = e.Item;
    int index = (int) myItem.Tag; // cast to your object type, int in this case
    // use the index
}
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - Control.Tag Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx)